# Sudo Apt Get Update Failed

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I'm trying to install Unity Tweak Tool, so I ran `sudo apt-get update`, but there's an error:

```
Get:54 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [2,440 B]
Get:55 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [2,396 B]
Get:56 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [980 B]
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:58 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:59 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:60 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_PH
Ign:61 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:63 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:58 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:59 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:60 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_PH
Ign:61 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:63 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:58 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:59 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:60 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_PH
Ign:61 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:63 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:58 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:59 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:60 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_PH
Ign:61 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:63 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:58 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:59 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:60 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_PH
Ign:61 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:63 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:58 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:59 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:60 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_PH
Ign:61 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:63 http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:64 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Err:65 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Err:66 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Fetched 1,126 kB in 2min 0s (9,352 B/s)
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://deb.playonlinux.com/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key 74F7358425EEB6176094CBB4E0F72778C4676186 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/varlesh-l/papirus-pack/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
$
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Your network connection is interrupted. Check once again.

Comment: My network connection is working properly.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when you can copy and paste the text in your question, select the text, and press the `{}` button.

Comment: Looks like connection to me.  If not try toggling off the repos giving errors under software properties

Answer (score 0):

Go to update manager and select other sources tab as in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2wpO.png).

unselect the ones "http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/*** " (all similar ones)

Do

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

[**NO MORE ERRORS SHOULD POP-UP NOW**]